# Switching back to Clang compiler for mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal

When compiling my code, in terminal I used to see:

```
>-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032  
>    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
>    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done  
>    -- Check for working CXX compiler:   >/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped  
>    -- Detecting CXX compile features  
>    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

For unrelated reasons, I wanted the compiler to be GCC instead of Apple Clang.  So in terminal, I set

```
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0_1/bin/gcc-11
```

and

```
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0_1/bin/g++-11
```

in an attempt to switch from clang to gcc as the compiler used in terminal.  But I would get the following error message:

```
>    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown  
>    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
>    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed  
>    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++  
>    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - broken  
>    CMake Error at   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
>The C++ compiler  
>/usr/bin/c++  
>is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

Now I want to switch back to clang and tried setting

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang
```

and

```
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

in terminal, but I now get the same error message as above where the compiler is unknown.

Comment: When you "switch" compiler using the environment variables, how and where and when do you set the variables? Do you regenerate build scripts? How do you build? What errors, if any, do you actually get? Please [edit] your question to include more details. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You need to clean out your CMake build directory, or at least the cache file `CMakeCache.txt`.